# ASP.NET MVC two controllers with same name, how to specify view location

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two controllers with same name in different namespaces

```
-Controllers
--AdminCp
---AccountController.cs
--Cp
---AccountrController.cs
```

And same view location structure

```
-Views
--AdminCp
---Account
----Login.cshtml
--Cp
---Account
----Login.cshtml
```

My Account controllers contains method Login

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

I also have custom `RazorViewEngine`

```
public ExtendedRazorViewEngine()
{
    ViewLocationFormats = new[]
    {
        "~/Views/AdminCp/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Cp/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Layout/{0}.cshtml",
    };
}
```

My routing uses `MvcCodeRouting`

```
routes.MapCodeRoutes(typeof (Controllers.HomeController));
```

But when i trying route to the action `Login` in `Cp namespace` i am getting view from `AdminCp namesapce`

```
http://example.com/cp/account/login ---> /views/admincp/account/login.cshtml
```

I know that i can pass path locatin in `View()` But... It looks ugly.

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see you created two folders: *AdminCp* and *Cp*. But MVC has built in functionality for this purposes: [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.98).aspx). By using Areas MVC sorts out these type of things for you

Comment: Thanks, i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have Areas to implement such function.A good link to start is :

[Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.98).aspx)

Also,you need to change your RouteConfig:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { area = "MyOneWay", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Furtermore,ypou can have your controller in below defined way:

```
namespace MyApp.Areas.MyOneWay.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        ...
    }
}

namespace MyApp.Areas.MySecondWay.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But i thought that with MvcCodeRouting i dont heed to create areas

Comment: ohhh..didnt checked you used MvcCodeRouting.I have not really worked much with MvcCodeRouting,lets wait for some other expert on this .

Comment: I think that ill create copy of project and will try to reimplement structure with areas. Thanks for help